# merge multiple Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have three dataframes that look like the following:

```
df1                 df2                     df3
name      id        name      colour        name      type
apple     1         apple     red           apple     fruit
banana    2         banana    yellow        banana    fruit
cucumber  3         cucumber  green         cucumber  vegetable
```

I would like to merge the dataframes so they look like this:

```
name      id  colour  type
apple     1   red     fruit
banana    2   yellow  fruit
cucumber  3   green   vegetable
```

I have tried using merge and concatenate but the output was not how I wanted it or had a bunch of NaN entries. Does anyone have an idea on how to effectively merge the dataframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple `merge` you can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce).

```
from functools import reduce
df = reduce(lambda x,y : x.merge(y, on='name'), [df1, df2, df3])
# this work like this : df1.merge(df2, on='name').merge(df3, on='name')
print(df)
```

```
# name      id  colour  type
# apple     1   red     fruit
# banana    2   yellow  fruit
# cucumber  3   green   vegetable
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
tmp = df1.merge(df2, on='name')
df3.merge(tmp, on='name')
```